# verify when $n=1$ and $a=x_0, b=x_1$ then Hermite cubics provide a Hermite interpolation of $[a,b].$

Tags: numerical-methods

How to verify when $n=1$ and $a=x_0, b=x_1$, then Hermite cubics provide a Hermite interpolation of [,].

I have derived the following $4$ polynomials form a basis for the degree $3$ polynomials on $[\alpha, \beta]$
$$H_0=3(\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha})^2-2(\frac{\beta-x}{\beta-\alpha})^3,$$
$$H_1=3(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha})^2-2(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta-\alpha})^3,$$
$$S_0=(\frac{(\beta-x)^2}{\beta-\alpha})-(\frac{(\beta-x)^3}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}),$$
$$S_1=(-\frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{\beta-\alpha})+(\frac{(x-\alpha)^3}{(\beta-\alpha)^2}),$$

But, I am unsure how to show that the two points interpolate given the conditions above.

Answer (score 1):

(Note $a = \alpha = x_0, b = \beta = x_1$.)  Check whether the functions you list have the properties that you want, namely:
$$
H_0(\alpha) = 1, \quad H_1(\alpha) = 0, \quad S_0(\alpha) = 0,\quad S_1(\alpha) = 0
\\
H_0(\beta) = 0, \quad H_1(\beta) = 1, \quad S_0(\beta) = 0,\quad S_1(\beta) = 0
\\
H_0'(\alpha) = 0, \quad H_1'(\alpha) = 0, \quad S_0'(\alpha) = 1,\quad S_1'(\alpha) = 0
\\
H_0'(\beta) = 0, \quad H_1'(\beta) = 0, \quad S_0'(\beta) = 0,\quad S_1'(\beta) = 1
$$

Comment: Hmm, so does that mean, all I have to do is for example, to find that $$_0()=1$$ I take the equation $$_0=3((−)/(−))^2−2((−)/(−))^3$$ and plug in  for x. After canceling out and everything, that would give me 1? Then I repeat the process for all of the other points? @GEdgar

Comment: Also, my follow up to that would be, why do those numbers you provided provide a Hermite interpolation of an arbitrary interval [a,b]. Does this mean for any given interval, those would be my set properties when n=1?  I guess my issue is understanding why n=1 is so special. @GEdgar